# Include text-editor in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, text-editor

I want to use text editor in my form on rails 3. Which is the best test editor for rails. How can I use this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice and full featured text editor is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). Also a nice and up-to-date gem exists to aid you with the integration (it also works with the popular gems for asset uploading, paperclip and carrierwave). You can have all the integration info [here](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/). I hope that helps.

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you why don't you take some ms to accept it :)?

Answer (score 1):

A nice and full featured text editor is CKEditor. Also a nice and up-to-date gem exists to aid you with the integration (it also works with the popular gems for asset uploading, paperclip and carrierwave). You can have all the integration info here. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I tried and was quite satisfied with [Tiny MCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

You can add/remove the features you want and customize it to your needs, and it is easy to integrate in a Rails application.

You can check and try the fully-featured version [here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)